# How to create a drag and drop table with sections in same way as block admin page?

Tags: drupal, drag-and-drop, themes, sections

How to make a drupal table with multiple sections that has support for drag and drop?

It should be similar to drupal block admin page:

[image: block admin page] .

I have only found examples on how to do it with on section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a nice article, in which you may get an [answer](https://www.computerminds.co.uk/quick-guide-using-drupal-add-tabledrag-and-enjoying-jquery-drag-and-drop-loveliness) but you may find the following guide more useful.

1. You may create the table with the ability to change wight. This is a sample of constructor:

```js
function mymodule_form_weights() {
  $data = array(
    array('id' => 1, 'title' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'active' => 0, 'weight' => -10),
    array('id' => 2, 'title' => 'Consectetuer adipiscing elit', 'active' => 1, 'weight' => -7),
    array('id' => 3, 'title' => 'Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam', 'active' => 1, 'weight' => 0),
    array('id' => 4, 'title' => 'Quis nostrud exerci tation', 'active' => 0, 'weight' => 5),
    array('id' => 5, 'title' => 'Ullamcorper suscipit lobortis', 'active' => 0, 'weight' => 3),
  );
  $form['#tree'] = true;
  foreach($data as $row) {
    $form['table'][$row['id']]['title'] = array(
      '#value' => $row['title'],
    );
    $form['table'][$row['id']]['active'] = array(
      '#value' => $row['active'] ? 'yes' : 'no',
    );
    $form['table'][$row['id']]['weight'] = array(
      '#type' => 'weight',
      '#default_value' => $row['weight'],
    );
  }
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'save',
  );
  return $form;
}
```

2. Themization

```js
function theme_mymodule_form_weights($form) {
  $rows = array();
  foreach(element_children($form['table']) as $id) {
    $form['table'][$id]['weight']['#attributes'] = array('class' => 'weight');
    $rows[$id]['class'] = 'draggable';

    foreach(element_children($form['table'][$id]) as $name) {
      $rows[$id]['data'][] = drupal_render($form['table'][$id][$name]);
    }
  }

  drupal_add_tabledrag('weights-form', 'order', 'sibling', 'weight');

  $output = theme('table', array('Title', 'Active', 'Weight'), $rows, array('id' => 'weights-form'));
  $output. = drupal_render($form);

  return $output;
}
```

3. hook_theme()

```js
function mymodule_theme() {
  return array(
    'mymodule_form_weights' => array('arguments' => array('form' => null)),
  );
}
```

Don't forget that it is php, not js as in snippet.